How do properly authorize an application to access PowerBI data?
I'm trying to setup a Blazor application that embeds PowerBI reports into a page.
I've been following the Embed Power BI content with service principal and an application secret tutorial and I am able to setup the App Owns Data example successfully.
Now I would like to publish this application so that an azure admin of another organization in Microsoft Entra can authorize the application and embed one of his reports. Eventually, the user wouldn't have to be signed in, and can delegate a different user (not in his Microsoft Org, but inside the application) to view a report, so I need to authorize the
application ( to manage PowerBI data without a signed in user.
There's an example for this use case here in .Net Framework. I've also seen the linked examples on that Readme here for .Net Core, but all of these examples require a manual user process of creating the service principal in Microsoft Entra, and authorizing that Service Principal in PowerBI.
I was able to register an application in Microsoft Entra (through App Registrations), and was also able to sign into my application as a user from another organization. This creates an "Enterprise Application" inside the user's tenant. Now, when I try to get a token for PowerBI using the clientId of my application, I get an "Unauthorized" message.
Here's the relevant code in my application:
appsettings.json
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "AuthorityUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<domain>", // this is the domain where I registered my app
    "ClientId": "<clientId>", // this is the clientId  of the registered app
    "TenantId": "organizations",
    "ScopeBase": ["https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"],
    "ClientSecret": "<secret>", // this is the secret I've added to the registered app
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

WebApplicationBuilder? builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.Configure<AzureAd>(config.GetSection(key: nameof(AzureAd)));
builder
    .Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(config);

builder
    .Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

builder.Services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();


I then add the [Authorize] attribute to my Blazor component, so when the user tries to access that page, they are prompted to authorize the app. This is where the "Enterprise Application" gets created in the user's tenant in Microsoft Entra. It looks like this successfully creates a service principal, since I can go to PowerBI and add this service principal as an admin of his PowerBI workspace.
However, when I try to generate a token for it:

IOptions<AzureAd> options = services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AzureAd>>();

string tenantSpecificUrl = options.Value.AuthorityUrl?.Replace("organizations", "<MyClientId>") ?? string.Empty;

var clientApp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(options.Value?.ClientId)
    .WithClientSecret(options.Value?.ClientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(tenantSpecificUrl)
    .Build();

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = clientApp
    .AcquireTokenForClient(options.Value?.ScopeBase)
    .ExecuteAsync()
    .Result;

string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = new(token, "Bearer");
var powerBIClient = new PowerBIClient(new Uri("https://api.powerbi.com"), tokenCredentials);

var groups = await powerBIClient.Groups.GetGroupsAsync();


I get an Unauthorized message.
I do believe there's something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm doing this, but I cannot find any examples of automatically creating a service principal anywhere.
Any help is much appreciated!

Did you allow access for service principals to call Power BI API by enabling the option in Admin Portal?

Posted the answer please check the below:)

To access or manage Power BI using multi-tenant Microsoft Entra ID application, check the below:
Create a Microsoft Entra ID multi-tenant application in TenantA and grant the below API permissions:

To create the Service Principal in TenantB, use the below endpoint and sign in with Global Admin of the TenantB:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/adminconsent?client_id=TenantAAppClientID


Now, in TenantB , the Service Principal will be created:

In TenantB, Go to the Power Bi portal and select the workspace you want to access, add Service principal as Admin or any role as your requirement:

Also enable Service principals can use Fabric APIs in Power Bi Admin portal:

For sample, I generated the access token by passing below parameters:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantBTenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: TenantAClientID
client_secret: TenantASecret
scope: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default


I am able to successfully get the reports of the workspace:


Note: If you want to fetch all the workspace of the Power BI, then make sure that the service principal must be a member of the workspace with role assigned in Power Bi portal.

In my scenario, I gave service principal role to only one workspace so when I call the /groups endpoint, I get only one workspace in response:
GET https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups


